# SQL CASE or not?

Tags: sql, case

i am trying to make a database back/front that contains client info, the info ranges from appointments and notes etc as we are a counselling service, if you miss(dna) 3 sessions you are technically discharged from our service what i want is to automate this process- help i am a self taught newbie, i am trying to do this using "SELECT CASE" but no idea here

```
id | nhi    | service | type | length | contactdate | notes
1  |PEB8132 | aod     | t32  | 20     | 2012-11-20  | notes go here
```

This is my table when they don't attend the length becomes dna and it is this that I want to use to flag after 3 failed attempts.

Comment: What uniquely identifies a person? nhi? (ie the part of "if -you- miss", what identifies -you-?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works in Oracle.

```
select nhi ,sum(case when length='dna' then 1 else 0 end) dna_count 
from table 
group by nhi  
having sum(case when length='dna' then 1 else 0 end)>3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to group together all the people who have a [length] = 'dna', showing a count of how many dna they have.

You also want to limit it to 'dna' > 3, but you can't use aggregates in `WHERE` clause, so we use `HAVING`.

You can add more columns to your `SELECT` statement, but you will also need to add them to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT nhi, count([length]) AS dna
FROM yourTable
WHERE [length] = 'dna'
GROUP BY nhi
HAVING count([length]) > 3
```

If you want to return all records and not just ones where [length]='dna' then you could use a CASE.

```
SELECT nhi, SUM(CASE WHEN [length]='dna' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dna
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY nhi
```

This assumes `nhi` is the id of the user, which is how you identify the person.

Extra Reading: [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: If id is just a sequence, this wouldn't be quite right, I think.

Comment: Ok, "sequential value" or primary key. Probably it will be a group by `nhi`.

Comment: thank you all , MikeSmithDev answer was close to what i wanted just changed > 3 to = 3 and got what i needed it now flags those who have 3 dnas and alerts the user to discharge